# Kivy not executing because PIL not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-imaging-library, kivy-language

So, I'm tinkering a bit with Kivy but I can't make it work, I only want to be able to start a screen for now but I am unable to do it. I don't know if the code I've been seeing online is bad or if there's a bug or I've done something wrong when installing it.
PS: I'm using Windows and PyCharm.

I've tried unininstalling and reinstalling Kivy and PIL and Pillow multiple times, writing `import PIL` and `Pillow` in `app.py`.

```
import os
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Here's the error that it gives me:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\j\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-11-07_20.txt

[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1

[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\j\Documents\PycharmProjects\Python_Test\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"

[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]

[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\j\Documents\PycharmProjects\Python_Test\venv\Scripts\python.exe"

[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded

[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)

[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\j\Documents\PycharmProjects\Python_Test\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 62, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\j\Documents\PycharmProjects\Python_Test\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py", line 13, in <module>
    from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
  File "C:\Users\j\Documents\PycharmProjects\Python_Test\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 62, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\j\Documents\PycharmProjects\Python_Test\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: just try: 'pip install sdl2-lib pillow' in your virtualenv

Comment: OK thank you! I was using the wrong interpreter and i didn't realise it until your answer, thank you so much I've been going mad with this

Comment: you're welcome !

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi - please consider submitting your comment as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to install the adequate dependencies in your virtualenv with pip :

```
 pip install sdl2-lib pillow
```